# How to print a triangle using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I have an assignment where I need to print a triangle pattern using recursion that looks like so:

```
*
**
***
****
***
**
*
```

It is generated by calling `triangle(4)`. Here is my code:

```java
public static void triangle(int height) {
    if (height == 0) {
        return;
    }
    triangle(height - 1);
    print_rowhelper(height, height - 1);
}

public static void print_row(int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
    
public static void print_rowhelper(int x, int y) {
    print_row(x);
    for (int i = 0; i<= y - 1; i++) {
        y -= 1;
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I've moved around variables and the best I've accomplished is this ...

```
*
**
***
****
```

... when the code is written in the following way:

```java
public static void triangle(int height) {
    if (height == 0) {
        return;
    }
    triangle(height - 1);
    print_row(height);
}
```

I've hit a wall when I try to make it decrease.

Comment: Just moving around variables won't get you far. You need to *think*. The algorithm is not that crazy, a hint: The recursive call doesn't need to be the first or the last thing you *do* in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add infromation about direction of `width` changing: `+1` or '-1'. Initially `inc = 1` and should be changed to `inc = -1` when `row == height`.

```
public static void triangle(int height) {
    triangle(1, 1, 1, height);
}

private static void triangle(int row, int width, int inc, int height) {
    if (width == 0)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        System.out.print('*');

    System.out.println();

    if (row == height)
        inc = -1;

    triangle(row + 1, width + inc, inc, height);
}
```

**Output:**

```
triangle(4);
System.out.println();
triangle(5);
    
*
**
***
****
***
**
*

*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Thanks so much I realize some of the advice i was being told, it never occurred to me to make another function of the same name to take those extra variables to determine if its increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add another example:

```java
class Main {
    
    private static void triangle(int n, int i) {
        printStars(i);
        if (i < n) {
            triangle(n, i + 1);
            printStars(i);
        }
    }
    
    
    static void triangle(int n) {
        triangle(n, 1);
    }
    
    
    static void printStars(int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        triangle(4);
    }
}
```

The trick is to use recursion in-between two print-statements. You can use a recursive call to print its depth in form of stars for two sides of the triangle. So we are using the fact that recursive calls are layered here.